# using multiple scope params in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord

In my Rails3 app I have AR scope which requires 3 parameters

Ex: I'm trying to get an error details for a given module between two code values

```
#select * from error_codes where error_module_id=1 and code >0 and code < 100

scope :latest_error_code, lambda{ |module_id, min, max|
    {:conditions => "error_module_id=#{module_id} and code >= #{min} and code <= #{max}"}
}
```

in my console I do

```
ErrorCode.latest_error_code(1,0,100)
```

But when I try to execute this, I'm getting the following error

```
multiple values for a block parameter (3 for 1)
```

and when i did some goggling, it appears to be that AR scope doent support multiple parameters

1 - is it true? (AR doent support multiple params for scope)
2 - Is there any other alternative?
3 - Am I doing something wrong here?

thanks in advance

Comment: I *believe* this is now working with Ruby 1.9+. It works fine on Ruby 2.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments):

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

So you probably want something more like this:

```
def self.latest_error_code(module_id, min, max)
    where(
        'error_module_id = :module_id and code between :min and :max',
        :module_id => module_id, :min => min, :max => max
    )
}
```